# Overriding the default field name limit in sphinx/docutils

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I am using [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for generating html documentation for a project. I make extensive use of [field lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#field-lists).

When generating html, each label/value pair is rendered as a single table row with two cells if the lenght of the label is at most 14 characters.

If the label of one pair is longer than 14 characters, the label/values are rendered as two table rows.

I want to increase the wrapping limit to a larger value (e.g. 40). I have found that the limit is controlled by the `--field-name-limit` option of docutils. However, I can't find how to set this value through sphinx.

I have created a `docutils.conf` file in the documentation root with the following contents:

```
[general]
dump_settings: 1
dump_internals: 1

[html4css1 writer]
field_name_limit: 40
```

The file is read when I run sphinx. The settings and internals are printed - because of the values in the `[general]` section. Among the printed values, `field_name_limit` is printed to have value `40`. Despite all that, the wrapping I described still occurs in the html output.

How do I set the value of `field_name_limit` so that I get the desired output?

Comment: FWIW, in Sphinx version v 1.6.6 the setting from docutils.conf is respected.

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx-1.2 will support docutils.conf for html writer if no objection.
https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/commits/67682aca

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach doesn't work because sphinx uses its own html writer.

However I think it should work, if you adapt the style for `field_name`.
I (once) used a custom css file with

```
.field-name {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or set it to a fixed width.

Comment: In Sphinx 1.6.6 that approach would not be viable as the Writer renders field name and value in 2 different table rows.

Comment: This doesn't not work because the wrapping is implemented in docutils html writer, which generates a different html elements, see: https://github.com/docutils/docutils/blob/84f7b36275804d110e05ac75688960e6f340e698/docutils/docutils/writers/html4css1/__init__.py#L916

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to override the setting in custom sphinx builder class extending original html builder, and set `self.settings.field_name_limit = 0` in `prepare_writing(self, docnames)` function. That said, this is a little overkill, unless you already have a custom builder class ...