# Changing the width of field list

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The length of the `parameter1` is causing the first row to be multiline rather than a single line; is there a way I can specify the width of field list directive?

```
:param parameter1: this is the first param..........
:returns:
```

[**try it here**](http://rst.ninjs.org/?theme=nature#CiAgICA6cGFyYW0gcGFyYW1ldGVyMTogdGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgZmlyc3QgcGFyYW0uLi4uLi4uLi4uCiAgICA6cmV0dXJuczogCg==)

Current output:

```
param parameter1:
    this is the first param..........
returns:
```

I want it to be

```
param parameter1: this is the first param..........
returns:
```

Comment: I found an [example in Pyramid docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.has_permission). The rendered HTML is in a table. If the appearance is not to your liking, then you could use a style sheet to override your theme's default. Are you using a different builder than HTML?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure about the builders, but I am using `sphinx-build` over rst files with `html_theme = 'bizstyle'`

Comment: In the context of Sphinx, a builder is the argument after `make`, e.g., `make html` or `make epub`. I'm not familiar with that theme, but you can learn how to override styles in your theme in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079202/2214933

Comment: You can customize `field_name_limit` in a docutils.conf file. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13029207/407651